# Path alias and taxonomy term view

Tags: path-aliases

I have PathAuto providing /term/[term:name] for terms of a specific vocabulary.

If I hover over the link for any of the terms, the path given is the alias.

When a term page is requested, e.g. /taxonomy/term/2, why isn't the page URL replaced with the alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the internal links /taxonomy/term/% are not used anymore, because all links Drupal puts on the page are aliased. If you want to prevent having multiple paths for the same page you can install https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect.

From the project page:

> - D8: Maintaining a canonical path and redirecting alternative URL's    like non-aliased path, path without language prefixes and so on
>   (Previously provided by Global redirect)